# Tailing a log file

Tags: python, linux, cherrypy

I want to add a log viewer tab to my website. The tab is supposed to print the whole log file, and after that print new lines (such as `tail -F` command in Linux) only. The client Side is in HTML and Javascript, and the server side is in Python.

Here is my tail Python function (I found it in the web):

```
@cherrypy.expose
def tail(self):
    filename = '/opt/abc/logs/myLogFile.log' 
    f = subprocess.Popen(['tail','-F',filename],\
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    p = select.poll()
    p.register(f.stdout)

    while True:
        if p.poll(1):
            print f.stdout.readline()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This code is indeed printing the whole log file. However, each time I add new lines to the file, the file has been printed from the beginning, instead of printing the new lines.

Any suggestions how to fix it? I'm pretty new in Python, so I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Can you think of a wrapper on top of your Logger class(which may be writing to the log file). Whenever your logger object receives a line to be printed in log file, the wrapper passes the line to UI aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `pytailer`

https://github.com/six8/pytailer

Specifically the `follow` command:

```
# Follow the file as it grows
for line in tailer.follow(open('/opt/abc/logs/myLogFile.log')):
    print line
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, i already tried to use `pytailer`. Don't know why, but nothing happen when i use the `follow` function (no errors, but no output as well).